# Vue enter transition on router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, transition

I'm following this image from vue docs

[image]

my html

```
<transition name="fade">
  <router-view/>
</transition>
```

and css

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-to, .fade-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

it fade out correctly but instantly pop in instead of fade-in. Why?

I've created [demo repository](https://github.com/BorysTyminski/vue-transition-issue) with just 2 components, steps to reproduce:

- git clone https://github.com/BorysTyminski/vue-transition-issue.git
- cd vue-transition-issue
- npm install
- npm run dev

And demo codesanbox:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-4e4oy

Comment: It should work. Are you sure the element doesn't have a stronger selector applying `transition-duration`? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure I created demo repo with just 2 routes and nothing more.

Comment: Did you check it? Is it not working on your machine as well?

Comment: I can't install random projects on machines at work, I'll check it from home, when I have time. You could have used codesandbox.io, btw.

Comment: Sure, here you go https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-4e4oy Just click huge link "Go to second"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is **both** your divs transition at the same time.
Which means they're both present in DOM at the same time.
Which means the second one, like any good ol' `<div>`, will be rendered below the first one.
Below as in *"...further down the page"*.
Unless it's absolutely positioned with `top:0`, of course.

So I guess you're missing...

```
#app {
  position: relative;
  > div + div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

[See it](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-q7xxw).

Comment: `<transition>` works like that and it's completely transparent. It basically doesn't care what it transitions as long as it's a DOM object.